# How to find ObjectId of Service Principal AAD

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, cicd

How to find object id of Service Principal (App Registration) by name in Azure ARM Template.

For DataFactory object id can be retrieved using:

```
 "objectId":"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('dataFactoryName')), '2018-06-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
```